# Minecraft server time loops between 6:20am and 7:20am

Tags: minecraft-java-edition, minecraft-java-edition-server

Me and my server's staff team are struggling for a quite a lot time with this. Our server is somehow set to be constantly at 6 am. More specifically, it always starts at around 6:20am and when it reaches ~7:20am, it resets and goes back to 6:20am, and this happens in an endless loop.

Neither me nor any of the staff did this, at least as far as I've been told. We tried everything, we even joined the server with special software that shows the cmd blocks to see if someone did it with a cmd block, but no. We also tried setting it to normal cycle with the command (`/gamerule doDaylightCycle`)

We also tried a bunch of plugins that promise normal day cycle but none worked. We also started the server with command blocks disabled but didn't work also.

Comment: my best guess is your server is corrupted but you may have a plugin on your server doing it, I would erase all the plugins and see if it works, if it doesn't then I would try and completely recreate your server and see if its your minecraft thats corrupted.

Comment: @Emptyisme I see. When saying "minecraft corrupted" which file do you mean, the world one or the .jar? Because I am updating the jar quite often, so it shouldn't be that.

Comment: It is most likely the world but as you know if its corrupted then you can't save it any of it easily so try taking your worlds out of the .minecraft folder and redownload minecraft and see if it works, if not then you will probably have to delete the world.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Im updating this because I fixed it.

It was a plugin afterall. BlockHunt v0.3.0. ALPHA.

I believe you should know its name in order to fix it too if you have this plugin.

Since the plugin wasnt working at all due to version incompability, I completely removed it for now.